Sending two different font styles on the text within a RichTextBox
In C#, how can I send/write a string to a RichTextBox control on my internal WinForm, where I can change the font style of a few words of the string to either Bold or Italic style and then go back to normal style?
Sample code: rtb.Text = "Hello *this* is my world.";
I haven't tried anything myself as I don't know how this can be done. As to what I'm looking to be able to do is send/write a string starting in a normal style and then being able to switch between two or more different styles as needed. For example, changing to bold style then go back to normal style one or more time within the same string.

Rremoved the visual-studio tag, not relevant. Add a tag that specifies what GUI platform you're using

Try a google for "C# rtf selection font style".

GUI platform: WinForms? WPF? MAUI? other?

In addition to answering Pac0's question, you also haven't stated whether the target RTB is in your OWN program, or if it is in an EXTERNAL program.  The approach would be very different based on the answer to that question...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Any time you set the .Text property of your RTB, you are going to lose all the formatting in it.
Instead, you would change the Font assigned to the current Selection. You could let the user make a selection, or you could search for a String. In the example below, I'm searching for "this" and changing it to Bold (button1) or Regular (button2):
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtb.Text = "Hello this is my world.";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String find = "this";
    int position = rtb.Find(find);
    if (position != -1)
    {
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String find = "this";
    int position = rtb.Find(find);
    if (position != -1)
    {
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}


Thanks this works great. I have a follow up question.   How do I code this if I want the selected text to be both Bold and Italicized?

You simply change FontStyle.Bold to FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic.
